# Why do the res of 'regexp' return NULL (Matlab)

Tags: regex, matlab, cell-array

I am trying to use the function regexp in Matlab. The first code is ok as follows:

```
          data={'ABCD' 'BCDE' 'ACBE' 'ADEBC '} % 3 AB, 2 BE, 2 BC

          %res = regexp( data, 'A.*.*B') % OK code
```

The above code is to count the A.*.B order in the data cell array. 
However, when I try to test with the celldata which is defined as follows:

```
            celldata = {'AB'; 'BE'; 'BC'}

            for kk=1:length(celldata)

                 res = regexp( data,'celldata{kk}(1).*.*celldata{kk}(2)')

            end
```

The 'res' value return NULL . Please kindly where is the bug here .Could anyone please help me to count the order of each element in celldata in data ? Thanks !

Comment: What's the desired result in this example?

Comment: @LuisMendo: The desired result in this example will be: Count 2 for AB order, count 2 for BE order and count 2 for BC order. They are the member of celldata. I want to check each of them in the 'data' cellarray

Comment: Sorry , count 3 for BC.

Answer (score 1):

Use the concatenation of strings

```
res = regexp( data, [celldata{kk}(1) '.*.*' celldata{kk}(2)])
```

to find the amount of occurences

```
for kk=1:length(celldata)
   res = cellfun(@(x) length(x), regexp( data,[celldata{kk}(1) '.*' celldata{kk}(2)]))
end
```

Comment: Thanks RoberStettler! The desired result in this example will be: Count 2 for AB order, count 2 for BE order and count 2 for BC order. They are the member of celldata. I want to check each of them in the 'data' cellarray. Your modification is nice with the first return of 'res'. How ever, in the count of second and the third element are like these below:

Comment: res =   [1]    []    [1]    [1]   % OK

However, the two returns below look strange. 
res =     []    [1]    [3]    []


res =   [2]    [1]    []    [4]

Comment: I hope they are should be: res = [1]    []    [1]    [1];


res = []    [1]    [1]    [];


res = [1]    [1]    []    [1]